# How to make this slide left to right instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

could someone show how could this slide left to right instead of it moving from top to bottom?

```
var current = 0,
  slides = document.querySelectorAll(".randtext");

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 1000);
```

current result https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/6rhdts5n/

Comment: What is "this" in this context? ... i dont see anything sliding or moving  in your code example?!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/6rhdts5n/ moves top to bottom, how can i have it slide left to right?

Comment: say text 1 appears slides away and text2 appears is what i mean

Comment: Put `.randtext {display: inline-block;}` to the CSS.

Comment: @Teemu could you show an example on fiddle?

Comment: Just copy the the CSS from my comment, and add it to your fiddle.

Comment: css ```.randtext { display: inline; }``` will align the containers with class="randtext"  horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var current = 0,
  slides = document.querySelectorAll(".randtext");

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 1000);
```

```css
.randtext {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.randtext:nth-child(n + 2) {
  opacity: 0;  
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="randtext">text 1</p>
<p class="randtext">text 2</p>
<p class="randtext">text 3</p>
</div>
```

**Whole file example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .randtext {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .randtext:nth-child(n + 2) {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <p class="randtext">text 1</p>
    <p class="randtext">text 2</p>
    <p class="randtext">text 3</p>
</div>
<script>
    var current = 0,
        slides = document.querySelectorAll(".randtext");

    setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
        }
        current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
        slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @amcquad thanks but now i wanted other text to appear after the first disappears like a image slider?

Comment: so you want text1 to be replace by text2 and then text3 to replace text2?

Comment: do i add jquery.min in header? i actually it

Comment: @JessicaBaby I've added an example whole file that works.

Comment: this was wht i wanted but on my page it wont run wonder why. but thanks a ton for helping me out. really appreciate it.

Comment: working, i am trying to add it inside a div but it does not stay inside the div why?